# stop audio tag when next audio tag starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to set up a webpage to promote myself as a pianist.

On one of the pages there are black and white keys that can be clicked. When a black key is clicked, an audio-player (I'm using the HTML5 audio-tag) appears. 
The problem is that when a next key is clicked, the audio from the previous one still continues. I think that the solution lies in Jquery(JS?), but I'm not really familiar with that yet.

The webpage is http://www.pianoson.nl/samples.htm

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="content">
        <div id="p1" class="panel">
            <audio controls="controls" src="media/hallelujah.mp3" codecs="mp3">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
            <p>Hallelujah - Leonard Cohen</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

And then here are currently 5 more songs, but it gets clearer when you see it.
This is the current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.sample').click(
function(){
    var $panel = $('#' + $(this).data("panel"));
    var $visibles = $('.panel:visible')
    $visibles.animate({
            'left' : '2000px',
            'top'  : '0px'
        },2000,function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });

    $panel.animate({
        'left' : '50%',
        'top'  : '50%',
        'margin-left' : '-175px',
        'margin-top' : '-35px'
    },2000).show();
});
});
```

If someone knows why the first audioplayer that 'flies in' only flies to the right, help on that topic is welcome too.

Comment: You don't need `$` in front of a JavaScript variable. Just a comment. Why don't you `.pause()` the audio player, before displaying the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for data. Here's what I suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var aud = $('audio'), itog = 0;
  $('.sample').each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
      var au = aud[i];
      au.toggle(2000, function(){
        if(itog === 0){
          au.animate({top: '50%', left: '50%', marginTop: '-35px', marginLeft: '-175px'}, 2000); itog = 1;   
        }
        else{
          au.pause(); au.animate({top:0, left:'2000px'}, 2000); itog = 0;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```